# How does one characterize surfaces with constant nonzero Gaussian and mean curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

I know that for any surface, the Gaussian curvature $K$ and mean curvature $H$ satisfy the inequality $H^2 \geq K$ , and the sphere is a surface where that inequality becomes an equation. Thus, the sphere has both constant Gaussian and mean curvature.

Are there other surfaces whose Gaussian and mean curvatures are constant and nonzero?

Comment: "Liebmann's theorem: The only regular (of class C²) closed surfaces in R³ with constant positive Gaussian curvature are spheres." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature#Surfaces_of_constant_curvature

Answer (score 4):

In one codimension one can be convinced of this quite easily.  Consider the tracefree curvature tensor
$
A^o = A - \frac{1}{n}Hg,
$
where $g$ is the metric, $A$ the second fundamental form, and $H$ the mean curvature.  For surfaces, the norm squared of $A^o$ satisfies:
$
|A^o|^2 = (k_1 - k_2)^2,
$
where $k_1$ and $k_2$ are the principal curvatures.  On the other hand,
$
2|A^o|^2 = 2|A|^2 - H^2 = -2(H^2 - |A|^2) + H^2 = -4K + H^2 .
$
So if $K$ and $H$ are constant, then the norm of the tracefree curvature tensor is also constant.  Further, the symmetry of $(\nabla A)$ implies that every component of $A^o$ is constant, and so the principal curvatures are themselves constant functions.  If their difference is zero, then the principal curvatures are equal and it follows that the surface is a sphere or a plane.  In higher codimensions this is more complicated.  If their difference is not zero, this contradicts the compactness of the surface.

Answer (score 2):

The only surfaces in Euclidean space with $K$ and $H$ both constant are: planes, spheres and right circular cylinders. It appears as an exercise in the Struik's book and a proof in "Curves and Surfaces", Montiel-Ros, Graduate Studies in Mathematics, vol. 69. AMS, 2009